# jpa (EclipseLink) wrong query for left join generated

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have trhee entities (this is my simplified version), there is no relation between `Entity1` and `Entity2` defined in DB. I need to select (using outer join) such records, where code in `Entity1` and `Entity2` and also country are the same:

Quite easy JPA query:

```sql
select a, b
  from Entity1 a
  left join Entity2 b
    on a.code = b.code
   and a.country = b.country
```

but when I did that, incorrect query is generated:

```sql
SELECT t0.ID, t0.CODE, t0.COUNTRY_ID, t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.COUNTRY_ID
  FROM tab1 t0 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 t1 ON ((t0.CODE = t1.CODE) AND (t0.COUNTRY_ID = t2.ID))
     , c t2
 WHERE (t2.ID = t1.COUNTRY_ID)
```

My opinion is, that correct query contains

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 t1 ON ((t0.CODE = t1.CODE) AND (t0.COUNTRY_ID = t1.COUNTRY_ID ))
```

without joining `t2`.

## Details

Ok, all details to reproduce the problem follows:

I have maven project with pom.xml as:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>betlista</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpa.eclipselink.tests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version><!-- I tried also 2.5.2, but the result is the same -->
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.181</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My entities looks like:

### Country:

```
package entity; // in "src/main/java"

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "c" )
public class Country {

    @Id
    long id;

    @Column
    private String code;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}
```

### Entity1:

```
package entity; // in "src/main/java"

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "tab1" )
public class Entity1 {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String code;

    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private Country country;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

### Entity2:

```
package entity; // in "src/main/java"

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "tab2" )
public class Entity2 {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String code;

    @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
    private Country country;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }


}
```

My JUnit test:

```
package tests; // in "src/test/java"

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:commons-test.xml" })
public class LeftJoinTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(em);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLeftJoin() {
        StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();
        queryString.append(" select a, b " );
        queryString.append("   from Entity1 a ");
        queryString.append("   left join Entity2 b " );
        queryString.append("     on a.code = b.code ");
        queryString.append("    and a.country = b.country ");
        Query query = em.createQuery(queryString.toString());
        List list = query.getResultList();
        Assert.assertEquals( 1, list.size() );
        Object[] oa = (Object[])list.get(0);
        Assert.assertEquals( 2, oa.length );
        System.out.println(list);
    }

}
```

where Spring configuraton file (`commons-test.xml` in src/test/resources) is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="entity" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:ddl.sql" />
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="eclipseLinkPu2" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="entity" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="eclispeLinkJpaVendor" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="eclispeLinkJpaVendor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

and in memory DB creation script (also in src/test/resources ) is

```sql
create table c (
    id number,
    code varchar2(20)
);

create table tab1 (
    id number,
    code varchar2(30),
    country_id number
);

create table tab2 (
    id number,
    code varchar2(30),
    country_id number
);

-- ****************
-- ***   data   ***
-- ****************

insert into c values( 1, 'US' );

insert into tab1 values ( 1, 'code1', 1 );
insert into tab2 values ( 1, 'code1', 1 );
```

[Eclipse link bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=453750)